# PDF fonts that include all possible gTLD chars

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader, print-to-pdf

I'm creating a generator for PDF documents in Ruby. When I include Chinese, Japanese and Cyrillic characters, they are displayed incorrectly.

It seems that when I'm generating the font I need to specify what font the text should be rendered with. Now this isn't the issue, but the fact that my documents will include all different possible chars that [gTLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_top-level_domain) supports.

So:

- Do you know any font for generating PDF documents that will include as many as possible chars (Asian, Europe, Symbols, …)  – ideally all chars that gTLD supports.
- When the client opens this document – is the PDF including my font in the PDF file, so when other computers open it, the font will be present? Is this by default? Or do I need to enforce this functionality?

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Any font for generating pdf that will handle Chinese, Cyrillic... ? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081212/any-font-for-generating-pdf-that-will-handle-chinese-cyrillic)

Comment: thx for edit @slhck, looks better

Comment: this question answered, just for complicity my problem was with Prawn gem generating pdf with several charset, my final solution on that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11081212/any-font-for-generating-pdf-that-will-handle-chinese-cyrillic/11097644#11097644

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do you know any font … that will include as many as possible chars (Asian, Europe, Symbols ..)

Search for pan-unicode fonts. The most widely distributed font with a large character set is probably Microsoft's "Arial Unicode".

> Ideally all chars that gTLD supports.

I suspect that gTLD supports the whole of Unicode. There is no single font that supports the whole of Unicode.

> Is pdf including my font in pdf file

I think this depends on what tools you use to produce the PDF and what options you select when doing so.

> Is this by default standard? Or I need to ensure/force this functionality

I think you need to ensure this happens if you need special fonts embedded. The PDF standard specifies some [standard fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format#Standard_Type_1_Fonts_.28Standard_14_Fonts.29) but these are probably not useful for wide Unicode coverage.

Comment: thanx, helped me. The way I did it I specify fall-back fonts in pdf and just use several fonts